# Rails: Deploying to Heroku, Many Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

Trying to deploy my rails app to Heroku for the first time, I ran into many problems. The app crashed, and you can look at the logs in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsx1b.png


Even worse, when I tried to look at my application locally, it failed to work on postgreSQL environment.It worked fine when I went back to use sqLite3 in database.yml. I thought the problem might be that I actually have to install postgreSQL, in addition to adding pg gem and running bundle install.

I went ahead to install  PostgreSQL with the one-click installer (Windows 7 64bit). After reboot, a simple rails server or bundle install commands started failing, so I reinstalled the entire ruby & rails.

Now rails server command works fine, and it prompts a different error when I try to look at my app on local environment. So right now I have pgAdmin III and Rails

```
PG::Error

fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452073/trying-to-set-up-postgres-for-ror-app-getting-error-fe-sendauth-no-password), but I couldn't find "pg_hba.conf." I guess the answer was based on a different OS.

And now again, the bundler is not working, giving me errors...

**Questions:**
1) Was I right to install postgreSQL with the one-click installer? Because this caused my ROR to "crash" somehow, and I had to reinstall rails altogether. 2) I think I am going to delete everything related to postgreSQL, reinstall Rails, and start everything from beginning. What are the steps that I have to take? All the references I've looked at do not seem to fit Windows environment.

In my gemfile, I have

```
gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
```

In my database, I have

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mangfeel_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mangfeel_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mangfeel_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

**Errors I'm getting at this moment, after installing PostgreSQL:**

```
c:\ruby\myapp>rails server
C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem railties (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

**When I run bundle install:**

```
Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**So I will just remove pgAdminIII, PostgreSQL, Ruby on Rails entirely, and start from scratch.**

I thought deploying wasn't going to be this hard, but moving from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL is taking more time and effort than I thought it would. I would really appreciate some help on this problem.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE: AFTER REINSTALLING EVERYTHING, I'M DOING THE SETUP AGAIN FROM SCRATCH.**

I checked that my SQLite3 version app worked fine. So I moved onto setting up postgreSQL. I got the following error when I first set up my postgreSQL. By setting up, I mean editing config/database.yml and installing the gem 'pg' and removing the gem 'sqlite3.' When I tried to connect to localhost:3000, I got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

After some research, I found that there could be more steps to setting the db. So I ran the bundle command,

```
bundle exec rake db:setup
```

But then in the console, I got the following error when I ran *bundle exec rake db:setup*.

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "host"=>"localhost", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=>"db/myapp_test", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
c:/ruby/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
```

When I tried to connect to localhost:3000, I got the above error again, instead of *ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished*.

**Question: What did I do wrong, and how do I solve the problem?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have error:

```
PG::Error

fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

You have good news, your app can work with PostgreSQL database now. (But you need to configure some thing)

After installing PostgreSQL, you can create new rails app using PostgreSQL by command:

```
rails new my_app -d postgresql
```

This is `database.yml` will be created:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_development
  pool: 5
  username: my_app
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_test
  pool: 5
  username: my_app
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_production
  pool: 5
  username: my_app
  password:
```

You see that, three database has `username` and `password` field, this is account user in Postgresql, three database in `database.yaml` file will created by this user. So you need to provide `username` and `password` for it. Default after install Postgresql, it created a user with username is `postgresql` and password is `postgresql`. You can use it.

If you want to use other user, just open `pgAdmin III` and create new user by right click on `Login Roles` and choose `New login role` to create new user with password. Then put that username and password to `database.yaml` file.

After that, all you need now, is find and open `pg_hba.conf` file to make some configure for app can work with PostgreSQL. I'm not using Windows for a long time, so I'm not sure where it is, but you can find in folder you installed PostgreSQL. Example, if you install on `E:\` partition, maybe you can find it in:

`E:\PostgreSQL\version\data`

After you found it, open and find a line:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local all all ident sameuser
```

Change it to:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local all all md5
```

Then restart your Postgresql database. To create database for app, run `rake db:create` or `rake db:create:all`. Now your app can using PostgreSQL database now, so happy :).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. Just to check again before installing Postgresql. 1) Is it right that aside from all the gemfile configuration, I have to download postgresql and install it (unlike SQLite3)? 2) Do I have to run Pgadmin everytime I want to test my app on local environment?

Comment: Everything is working very well! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: 1) You have to download and install PostgreSQL on your machine, if not you can't use PostgreSQL with your app. 2) No, you don't need to run PgAdmin everytime. If you want to check some thing, just run `rails console` and write some active record query to get data to check.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Rails, but here is one of my YAML files for a recent deployment i did on heroku with POSTGRES

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
host: localhost
database: dbname_development

production:
adapter: postgresql
host: localhost
database: dbname_production
```

Seems like you are missing a parameter called host in case of postgres deployment

Comment: It throws: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Comment: Make sure postgres is running on the default port. otherwise add the port number as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to Move From SQLite3 to PostgreSQL on Windows, for an Existing Rails App to Deploy To Heroku:**

1. In your **Gemfile**, find `gem 'sqlite3'` and change it to `gem 'pg'`. Run `bundle install`.
2. Download Postgres from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/). Choose the one-click installer and select your OS environment (32 or 64 bit). During installation, do NOT choose to install any extra software it recommends you to install. It will possibly mess up your existing Rails and you will have to reinstall Rails.
3. Now go to **config/database.yml,** and change it to the following format. The current one is set for SQLite3 and is missing some fields necessary for PostgreSQL.

   ```
   development:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: my_app_development
      pool: 5
      username: my_app
      password:

   test:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: my_app_test
      pool: 5
      username: my_app
      password:

   production:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: my_app_production
      pool: 5
      username: my_app
      password:
   ```

The adapter is different, and there are fields for username and password. The default username and password is postgresql, but if it doesn't work (it didn't work for me), then go to your pgAdmin, create a new login role to make another username/password (check the option to make it a super user) and use that.

4, At this point, you can create a new app by running

```
rails new my_app -d postgresql
```

Run your local server, and try connecting to localhost:3000 to see if the welcome page is showing.

5, If everything is working fine, then all you need to do is create a new PostgreSQL database, and migrate your existing models to it. Run

```
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

Done! Now check if your existing app is working fine locally, and try deploying your app to Heroku.