# Rails: Heroku Deploying for the First Time Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I thought the problem was that I was using a SQLite3, so I migrated to PostgreSQL but the problem persists. The app works fine locally. I open my app with heroku open, it gives me the following error:

```
Application Error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details..
```

I tried to find the resolution by looking at the logs but failed, so I need someone's help. **Here are my logs and I appreciate any help!**

```
2012-11-19T00:55:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 3545`
2012-11-19T00:55:39+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your
the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-11-19T00:55:39+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your
the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/formtastic.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Formtastic (NameError)
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'

2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-11-19T00:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-11-19T00:55:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-11-19T00:56:34+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=fast-savannah-6843.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-11-19T00:56:34+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-savannah-6843.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-11-19T00:57:44+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=fast-savannah-6843.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-11-19T00:57:44+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-savannah-6843.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: You've got Formtastic included in your gemfile, right?

Comment: yes! group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'

Comment: Have you tried doing bundle install before running rails server?

Comment: Yes, and bundle install gave me errors too. I think there's a problem with heroku.bat and I need to set the PATH to C:\railsinstaller\Ruby1.9.3 .. do you think that's correct?

Comment: Ok, the problem was that the "RailsInstaller" and "heroku-toolbelt" were causing each other a problem, so I decided to remove heroku-toolbelt and include it as a gemfile instead. However, I still do not see what my problem was with the deployed app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For first-time deployers, here are the problems I had, and how I solved them:**

**1. RailsInstaller and Heroku Toolbelt are not perfectly compatible**: If you encounter problems after you install Heroku toolbelt, I suggest you delete railsinstaller and heroku toolbelt alltogether, and install railsinstaller again. Then, in your gem file, simply add `gem 'heroku'` and run bundle install. I didn't need any extra stuff to successfully deploy my app. *Heroku Toolbelt installs ruby 1.9.2 v, and adds wrong path to your preference. You can choose to manually fix this PATH to the right location, ex) C:RailsInstaller:Ruby1.9.3 but I found it easier to reinstall everything.*

**2. You have to migrate from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL**: follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439276/rails-deploying-to-heroku-many-problems) if you are unsure how to do it.

**3. Follow Heroku tutorial to finally deploy your app**: follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3). If you get errors that say something along line with "objects do not exist," try running `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Good luck deploying!