# Postgresql with Rails 4.0.1 -- not running on localhost:3000 or deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

When I try to run my sample Rails 4.0.1 app on my localhost:3000, I get this error:

PG:: ConnectionsBad
FATAL: role "myapp" does not exist.

I'm running on Maverick OSX and using Ruby 2.0.  I created my sample app exactly as https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4 instructed, but when I tried '$ rails server' , I got the error above.  I'm running the current Postgres. I attempted to change pg_hba.conf according to other stackoverflow advice, but so far it's still not working.  I can run on my localhost with MySQL3, but cannot with Postgresql.  I want to run Postgresql in Development, Test and Production as per Heroku's advice.

Ref:
[Rails: Deploying to Heroku, Many Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439276/rails-deploying-to-heroku-many-problems), 
[Repairing postgresql after upgrade to OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565708/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrade-to-osx-mavericks)

Comment: What does your `database.yml` look like?

Comment: what's the output of `ps auxwww | grep postgres`

Comment: Here is my database.yml...

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: AAA_website_heroku_development
  pool: 5
  username: AAA_website_heroku
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: AAA_website_heroku_test
  pool: 5
  username: AAA_website_heroku
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: AAA_website_heroku_production
  pool: 5
  username: AAA_website_heroku
  password:

Comment: Did you create the database?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your problem:

```
username: AAA_website_heroku
```

For the default install of PG, the username is the same username as your computer user account.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgresql database, you should specify a username and password for your databases. In your `database.yml`, I don't see your passwords. Try create a user in Postgresql  and specify username and password of that user in `database.yml` and run again.