# Rails server not working on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

A Rails newbie here. I'm having problem with cloned Shopify app to develop on Cloud9. I need to run on rails s -b $IP -p $PORT to see a preview, but i can't access to first page at all. it showed 500 server error (full msg: A static HTML page can contain a simple dependency free script to set the top bar to a 500 server error. This page can be found in 'public/500.html'.)

I tried to find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375740/pgconnectionbad-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452073/trying-to-set-up-postgres-for-ror-app-getting-error-fe-sendauth-no-password). Both of them suggest to modify pg_hba.conf But I check my file and it's the same as them so I didn't modify it at all.

I did try to change my database.yml from host: localhost -> host: /var/run/postgresql but I got another error msg. It seems not a solution.

Could you help me?

Here's my log

```
icys@c_app:~/workspace (master) $ rails s -b $IP -p $PORT

=> Booting Thin

=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)

Maximum connections set to 1024

Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, CTRL+C to stop

Started GET "/" for 171.96.244.172 at 2015-09-01 13:44:42 +0000

PG::ConnectionBad (fe_sendauth: no password supplied

):

activerecord (4.2.0)   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'

quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'

rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'

rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'

activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'

rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'

actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'

rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'

rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'

thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'

thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'

thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'

thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'

thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'

eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'

eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'

thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'

thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'

rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'

rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'

railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'

bin/rails:4:in `require'

bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here's my database.yml

```
development:

adapter: postgresql

encoding: unicode

database: development

pool: 5

host: localhost

username: action

password:
```

Here's my pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket

local all postgres peer

# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

local all all peer

# IPv4 local connections:

host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5

# IPv6 local connections:

host all all ::1/128 md5
```